# How to export graphs from Matlab to word file

Tags: matlab

Is there any efficient way to import Matlab graphs to word file, I’ve lots of graphs and I won’t be partial to import them individually, is there any way to do it programmatically?

Comment: Do you need a Word document in particular?  Matlab has a few ways to export figures to a PDF.

Comment: I suppose you could use ActiveX to do it but it seems like it would be more effort to figure out than it's worth. [This newsgroup post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/170563) may be useful.

Comment: @excaza - One of my colleagues created a script that uses ActiveX to export graphs to PowerPoint, so I imagine it's not too far of a leap to Word